# WAS 9 how to use servlet 3.0 in Websphere 9?

Tags: servlets, servlet-3.0, servlet-mapping, servlet-3.1, websphere-9

As per the given specs WAS9 is using JAVAEE 7 and related specs . I want to use servlet spec 3.0 due to some constraints . Is there any way to configure it . I am using plain profile (No liberty profile).

The constraints is ***I am having two servlets with same URL mapping which is not allowed in servlet spec-3.1***.

As per give [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/cweb_servlet_behavior.html) I can use servlet spec 3.

How can I make WAS 9 to use servlet spec 3?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to make WAS 9 use the servlet 3.0 specification. You should change the URL pattern for the servlet mapping. If you use WebSphere Liberty then you could use either the servlet-3.0 feature or the servlet-3.1 feature in your server.xml. This would allow you on WebSphere Liberty to get the behavior you require.